# Adding Web Reference (C#) in visual studio does not show the web reference folder contents

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I added the web reference ([1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) to one of the Visual Studio(2010) project(***Type:Library***) in my current solution. Usually when I add this I have a web reference folder created and a couple of files under that folder (wsdl, proxy reference.cs files). But i don't see the files. But I can view the files when seen through windows explorer.

I tried to add it to another project(***Type:Windows Service***) in the same solution and I can see the files under it after I added the references.

***Note***: The web reference is just a wsdl file on my local computer and the web service i am trying to add is internal (not outside firewall)

I tried to reload the project, open and close the project and still I don't see the files listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files are hidden by default. Select a service folder and then click on the "Show hidden files" option in the solution explorer and then click on the "Refresh" button in the solution explorer. This will show you all the wsdl, disco and the reference.cs files in the solution explorer.